# How to pass data to a template in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

In the template below, I am trying to get the name of the court (that is captured through the "establishment" field).  I am passing "club_id" through the avail_times function, but how do I pass the "establishment" field passed through the template from this?

The model:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    establishment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.establishment

class Available(models.Model):
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club)
    court = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    avail_time = models.DateTimeField('available time')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.court
```

The function:

```
def avail_times(request, club_id):
courts = Available.objects.filter(club__id=club_id)
return render_to_response('reserve/templates/avail_times.html', {'courts': courts})
```

The template:

```
<h1>All available courts for {{ court.club }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for court in courts %}
    <li>{{ court }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: As an aside you should be using courts = Available.objects.get(club__id=club_id), it's faster.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
def avail_times(request, club_id):
  courts = Available.objects.filter(club__id=club_id)      
  if courts.count() > 0:
    club_name = courts[0].club.establishment
  else:
    # no results found for this club id!

# perhaps it is better to check explicity if the club exists before going further, 
# eg. Club.objects.get(pk=club_id)
# is club_id passed in as a string? I haven't used django in awhile somethign 
# worth looking into?

return render_to_response('reserve/templates/avail_times.html', {'courts': courts, 'club_name': club_name})


<h1>All available courts for {{ club_name }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for court in courts %}
    <li>{{ court.club.establishment }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You span foreign key relationships using dot notation.  You have to go "through" the foreign key to get to the `Club` model.  This is done through accessing the `club` attribute.  So additionally supposed you wanted to access both the establishment name AND the address, you could add `<li>{{ court.club.address }}</li>` to display the address too.

Be careful though, you can use django debug toolbar to see how many queries are being executed.  if you have a lot of courts you might notice a performance hit. Just something to keep in mind.

Courts is a queryset object.  You are trying to access property of `court.club` which doesn't exist, as you've probably noticed django fails silently when this happens.  There are a couple ways of getting club name.

You might want to give some thoughts to your schema.  Can clubs have multiple courts?? If not it is "better" to use `.get` as Zahir suggested.  If it can have multiple courts then you should look into a ManyToMany relationship to better reflect this.

Comment: I am trying to get the court establishment name to show on the first line.  When I include "court.club.establishment" on the first line with <h1> it doesn't work. Why is this and how do I get this to show?

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm new to django...clubs can have multiple courts, how would you suggest editing the schema?  What do you mean by manytomany relationship?

Comment: This is great! I was wondering how to pull from multiple models into one view.

Answer (score 1):

Use `render()` because `render_to_response()` is removed since **Django 3.0**:

**views.py**:

```py
def avail_times(request, club_id):
    courts = Available.objects.filter(club__id=club_id)      
    if courts.count() > 0:
        club_name = courts[0].club.establishment
    else:
        # no results found for this club id!

    return render(
        request, 
        'reserve/templates/avail_times.html',
        {'courts': courts, 'club_name': club_name}
    )
```

**Django Template**:

```
<h1>All available courts for {{ club_name }}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for court in courts %}
    <li>{{ court.club.establishment }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```