# How can I put data from api to django

Tags: python, django, api

I have stored some data in python and now I want to display it in django how can I do that?

```
animeUrl = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime"
animeResponse = requests.get(animeUrl).json()

def topAnime():
    for idx, video in enumerate(animeResponse['data']):
        animeUrl = video['url']
        title = video['title']
        status = video['status']
        type =  video['type']   
        images = video['images']['jpg']['image_url']   
        #if status == "Currently Airing":
        print (idx+1,":",animeUrl, ":", status, ":", title, ":", type, ":", images)    
topAnime()
```

this is my stored data and now I want to display it on website, how can I do that?
I'm newbie in django I'm looking for some suggestions

I have tried using templates but it didn't worked

Comment: I recommend that you work through the tutorial from the official django documentation. This is a good place to start in order to learn the basic concepts in Django. From there you will have a better idea of how your ideas can fit into the django framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new, I highly recommend that you build your first project by following the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/), it helps you grasp some key concepts. You can find your solution at the [third part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/).

But, to answer your question:

In your App's views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
    
def get_animes(request):
    url= "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime"
    response= requests.get(url).json()
    return render(request, 'animes.html', { 'data': response['data']})
```

In your App's urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
    
urlpatterns = [
    path('animes/', views.get_animes, name='animes'),
]
```

In your animes.html file:

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {{ obj.url }}
    <br>
    {{ obj.title }}
    <br>
    {{ obj.status }}
    <br>
    {{ obj.type }}
    <br>
    {{ obj.jpg.image_url }}
    <br>
    <br>
{% endfor%}
```

In your root urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myApp.urls')),
]
```

Finally, run your development server:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Open your browser and send a request to your URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/animes/
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered here :
[How to pass data to a template in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601126/how-to-pass-data-to-a-template-in-django)

In order to display data in django from url to html files there are two ways

**Method 1: Rendering the template along with the data**
[Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/)

How to use it in the project : [Render Html Pages in django](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

You can easily set up the jinja syntax with the help of above two links

Method-2 : Using django Rest Framework [Django Rest Framwork](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Prefer this method if you have already worked with api's and worked with sending ajax requests with java scripts

Sample Code structure for Method - 1:
main.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
animeUrl = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime"
animeResponse = requests.get(animeUrl).json()

def topAnime():
    for idx, video in enumerate(animeResponse['data']): # z [data] wyciaga mi nastepujace rzeczy ktorze sa pod spodem
        animeUrl = video['url']
        title = video['title']
        status = video['status']
        type =  video['type']   
        images = video['images']['jpg']['image_url']   
        #if status == "Currently Airing":
        print (idx+1,":",animeUrl, ":", status, ":", title, ":", type, ":", images)    
topAnime()

def requestSender(request):
    return render(response, "index.html", data=topAnime())
```

index.html

```html
<body>
<p> {{ data }} </p>
</body>
```